# Eigenvectors in Numpy: Very bad numerics? Did I do something wrong?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, numeric

For some calculations I need an eigenvalue decomposition. Now I tried to evaluate the functions of numpy and noticed that there is a very bad behavior! Look at this:

```
import numpy as np
N = 3
A = np.matrix(np.random.random([N,N]))
A = 0.5*(A.H + A) #Hermetian part
la, V = np.linalg.eig(A)
VI = np.matrix(np.linalg.inv(V))
V =  np.matrix(V)
```

/edit: I chose a hermetian Matrix now, so it is normal.

The mathematics say that we should have VI * VH = 1, and VH * A * V = VI * A * V = D, where D is the diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues. The result which I got from a random matrix was:

```
print(A.H*A - A*A.H)
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]
```

this shows that A is normal.

```
print(V.H*A*V)
[[  1.71513832e+00   5.55111512e-17  -1.11022302e-16]
 [ -1.11022302e-16  -5.17694280e-01   0.00000000e+00]
 [ -7.63278329e-17  -4.51028104e-17   1.28559996e-01]]

print(VI*A*V)
[[  1.71513832e+00  -2.77555756e-16  -2.22044605e-16]
 [  7.49400542e-16  -5.17694280e-01  -4.16333634e-17]
 [ -3.33066907e-16   1.70002901e-16   1.28559996e-01]]
```

This two work correct, since the off-diagonals are very small and on the diagonal we have the eigenvalues.

```
print(VI*V.H)
[[ 0.50868822 -0.57398479  0.64169912]
 [ 0.16362266  0.79620605  0.58248052]
 [-0.84525968 -0.19130446  0.49893755]]
```

This should be one, but its far away from it.

So folks, now tell me, what has gone wrong during making the eigenvectors, even in this small example?? Can anybody tell me when I have to care while using this functions, and what I can do against the great missmatch?

Comment: Can you post a link to the mathematics formula?

Comment: The numerical results are all correct, but you are thinking about properties of hermitian matrices, which do not apply when `A` is non-hermitian.

Answer (score 6):

Quote from [numpy.linalg.eig documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html):

> Likewise, the (complex-valued) matrix of eigenvectors v is unitary if the matrix a is normal, i.e., if dot(a, a.H) = dot(a.H, a), where a.H denotes the conjugate transpose of a.

Obviously, in the example you have, `A^H A != A A^H`, so the matrix `V` is not unitary.
Therefore, `V.T.conj()` is not related to the inverse of `V`.
The most common case where this assumption is correct is for hermitian matrices.

Comment: Matrix A is normal <=> Matrix A is diagonizable <=> I can find N different Eigenvalues for A. I guess I have a problem in thinking here?

Comment: "Diagonalizable" and "diagonalizable by unitary matrices" are different things.